# Including a clickable YouTube thumbnail (or clicking any picture) to show a video

Tags: support

My answer to this question [Rock crushing hands, how to make it possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/132105/rock-crushing-hands-how-to-make-it-possible) show two pictures. The first is of a red crab claw.

The second is a still captured from a YouTube video. My *text* link to the video works perfectly but I would prefer that people be able to click *the picture itself* to reach the video, i.e. treat it as a clickable thumbnail.

Can this be done within the parameters provided by SE?

P.S. - This was my attempt. [image]  There's a clickable link there but my picture is missing:

Comment: It takes a little bit of fiddling with the markdown, but it's pretty simple once you figure it out.

Comment: I've fiddled (see above) and I get a clickable little square but my picture is missing. Any ideas? Here is the attempt - <a href="https://youtu.be/UFlX8U243yo"><img src="https://https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQCwz.png" /></a>

Answer (score 5):

You're using HTML.  Use Markdown instead, along with the embedded editor utilities.  Using pictures is slightly harder, but not terribly so.  To make it easier:

1. Add a link.  That gives you markdown such as: `[this is a link][1]` which adds the link to the bottom of the post: `[1]: http://whereveryouwanttogo.com`
2. Add a picture.  That gives you the markdown `[![enter image description here][2]][2]`, with the link being `[2]: https://imageuploadurl`
3. Update the **second** square bracket link to your linked article square bracket.    ie. `[![enter image description here][2]][1]`

That will display the picture, and clicking on it will send the user to the link, instead of opening the picture full screen.